# How can I turn off the "You have unspent Sync Points!" Message?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

So the game is new but one thing that really annoys me is the message that pops up on the right of the screen telling me that I **have unspent Sync Points!**

It's really annoying and I'm just trying to save them to level up certain skills.

This wouldn't be an issue if it didn't hover over a lot of interesting information and sometimes mission information!

I've scoured the menus and haven't found an option to do so.

**Does anyone know how to turn these messages off?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Go to **HUD Settings**
>
> Turn off **Tips**

And those messages will disappear.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I turned off Tutorials as I didn't have a Tips item

Answer (score 1):

I think if you turn off **Tips** in the **HUD Settings** it should stop coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Glad I'm not the only one it bugs. To expand on others' answers, Menu > Options > HUD Options and turn off UPDATES. Unfortunately this turns off all updates.